# Añadir columna a un dataframe de otro dataframe si cumple condición

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando añadir una columna de un `dataframe` a otro si se cumple la condición de igualdad.

Tengo un `dataframe` llamado **df1** que tiene 4 campos:

- Operador
- Mes
- Año
- ValorA

Y otro dataframe llamado **df2** que tiene también 4 campos:

- Operador
- Mes
- Año
- ValorB

En df2 es posible que haya más operadores que en df1, pero lo que quiero es llevar el campo ValorB al df1, porque si el operador está en ambas, estarán escritas de igual forma.

Para ello he usado de la librería `tidyverse` la función `inner_join`, pero no logro añadir ese campo, usando a su vez `mutate` para crear esa columna nueva.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(ValorB = inner_join(df1, df2, by = "Operador"))
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado de un `inner_join` es otro `data.frame` que no podrías asignar como lo estás haciendo. Además tengo la impresión que la relación no es solo por `Operador` sino también por `Mes` y `Año`. Planteamos el `join`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data_frame(Operador=1:5, Mes=1:5, Año=1:5, ValorA=runif(5))
df2 <- data_frame(Operador=1:5, Mes=1:5, Año=1:5, ValorB=runif(5))

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = c("Operador", "Mes", "Año")) 


# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Operador   Mes   Año ValorA ValorB
     <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1        1     1     1 0.294  0.264 
2        2     2     2 0.532  0.289 
3        3     3     3 0.0831 0.0231
4        4     4     4 0.218  0.691 
5        5     5     5 0.277  0.711
```

En caso que la relación solo necesites plantearla  por `Operador`

```
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = "Operador") 

# A tibble: 5 x 7
  Operador Mes.x Año.x ValorA Mes.y Año.y ValorB
     <int> <int> <int>  <dbl> <int> <int>  <dbl>
1        1     1     1 0.294      1     1 0.264 
2        2     2     2 0.532      2     2 0.289 
3        3     3     3 0.0831     3     3 0.0231
4        4     4     4 0.218      4     4 0.691 
5        5     5     5 0.277      5     5 0.711
```

Tienes que tener en cuenta que las columnas con idénticos nombres, se renombran automáticamente: `Mes.x` y `Mes.y` o `Año.x` y `Año.y`. Y el otro dato importante, es que en este caso es innecesario cualquier `mutate` ya que trasladas la columna nueva completa.

Comment: Gracias por tus magníficas aclaraciones, una vez más.